# Spaceing in TMemo not matching text file

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a text file with this:

```
  _____ _           ___     _    _ 
 |_   _| |_  ___   / __|_ _(_)__| |
   | | | ' \/ -_) | (_ | '_| / _` |
   |_| |_||_\___|  \___|_| |_\__,_|
```

When I load the file into a `TMemo`, it looks like this:

[image: image of result]

How can I fix this? Why is it doing this?

I'm using Delphi 10.2.

```
procedure TFrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo2.Lines.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\user1\Desktop\demo\thegrid.txt');
end;
```

Comment: You might try to give the memo a fixed width font, like Courier New and try again.

Comment: i tried that and still looks the same maybe a small difference but over all still smashed

Comment: This did work after all i was not reading your response  correctly.. The ASCII art was done in Courier New.  but had to switch the MEMO to that font also.

Comment: If you don't like the serifs, use something like Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, etc.

Comment: Lucida Console. It's the font Notepad uses too.

Comment: @GolezTrol: not mine. Mine uses Consolas. And this site uses Consolas too, if it can (otherwise Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, or a few others).

Answer (score 3):

You're using a variable-width font to display it, and ASCII art like that only looks right when it's displayed with a fixed-width font.

Comment: if i change the font , it would also change the look.  Is there anyway to to use this font and make it look correct ?

Comment: Not without remaking all of the ASCII art to work with that font.

Comment: No, there is no way to use a variable width font and make it fixed width, unless you "manually" draw each character at the right spot. But much easier is using a sans-serif fixed width font (like e.g. Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console -- which is what the CSS for the display above uses) to make it look good.